Get pathname on 404 pages (next.js server component)?
Is there a way to get the "not found" pathname on a server side 404 page (not-found.tsx under app dir)
The constraint is a statically generated catch all route export const dynamic = 'force-static'
I tried a workaround to put the pathname in a custom header in the middleware, it works on the dev server, but the force-static strips the headers at prod runtime.
The use case being a smarter 404 with more context and CTAs than a static page/component.
a 'use client'; not-found.tsx has access to usePathname(), but is not ideal for my use case.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/not-found#data-fetching need the headers it seems

useRouter is also a way to get pathname

useRouter will force it to be a client component @NaveenNizam
headers get striped out in prod if you use force-static @cmgchess
